# LINQ: можно ли объединить запросы SingleOrDefault и Where в один?

Tags: c#, инспекция-кода, linq, рефакторинг

Есть код консольного приложения

```
static void Main()
{
    var inputDictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>
    {
        { "protocol", 3},
        { "foto1", 6},
        { "foto2", 4},
        { "foto3", 4},
        { "foto4", 5},
        { "some", 5}
    };            

    // Get fotos
    var resultDictionary = inputDictionary.Where(kvp => kvp.Key.StartsWith("foto") && kvp.Value > 2) // 1
                                          .Take(2).ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);
    if (resultDictionary.Count < 2)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("NO");
        System.Console.ReadKey();
        return;
    }

    // Get protocol
    var protocolKeyValuePair = inputDictionary.SingleOrDefault(kvp => kvp.Key == "protocol" && kvp.Value > 2); // 2
    if (protocolKeyValuePair.Equals(new KeyValuePair<string, int>())) // check on null
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("NO");
        System.Console.ReadKey();
        return;
    }

    // Merge
    resultDictionary.Add(protocolKeyValuePair.Key, protocolKeyValuePair.Value);

    // Success
    foreach (var kvp in resultDictionary)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine($"{kvp.Key}: {kvp.Value}");
    }

    System.Console.ReadKey();
}
```

**В реальности переменная `dictionary` это входной параметр метода. А также записей с именами ключей protocol и foto и вовсе могут не быть поэтому необходима тщательная валидация.**

**НЕОБХОДИМО** взять три пары ключ/значение из `dictionary`. Одна из которых должна иметь имя ключа *protocol*, а две остальные имя ключа по маске *foto* *. У всех трех пар значение должно быть больше 2.

В коде я вроде добился этого результата. Я сделал это как вы видите двумя LINQ-запросами и еще куча кода потребовалось.

---

### Вопрос

Можно ли как-то оптимизировать код? К примеру добиться того же эффекта одним LINQ-запросом?

Comment: Если вы все равно потом берете значение `Count`, то `Any` теряет свой смысл и можно обойтись вообще без него.

Comment: @AlexKrass я изменил код. Там была ошибка, которая не предполагала, что `dictionary` может и вовсю не иметь ключей с именами `protocol` и `foto*`.

Comment: можно использовать [Aggregate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb548651(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поскольку у Вас идет отбор разных данных по количеству, то объединить все в один запрос достаточно проблематично. Проще отдельно взять два запроса и объединить их в один результат.

```
var inputDictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>
{
    { "protocol", 3},
    { "foto1", 6},
    { "foto2", 4},
    { "foto3", 4},
    { "foto4", 5},
    { "some", 5}
};  

var result = inputDictionary.Where(p => p.Key == "protocol" && p.Value > 2).Take(1).Union
    (
        inputDictionary.Where(p => p.Key.Contains("foto") && p.Value > 2).Take(2)
    );

if(result.Count() != 3)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("NO");
}
else
{
    foreach (var kvp in result)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine($"{kvp.Key}: {kvp.Value}");
    }
}

System.Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Код работает. Спасибо. Но я убрал `Take(1)`, т.к. в `Dictionary` ключи не повторяются.

Answer (score 0):

Есть еще такой варинат

```
var t = inputDictionary.Where(g => g.Key.Contains("foto")).Take(2).ToList().AddExtensionDictionary(inputDictionary.FirstOrDefault(g => g.Key == "protocol"));

            foreach (var kvp in t)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Key-{kvp.Key} | Value-{kvp.Value}");
            }

            System.Console.ReadKey();



static class AddExtension
    {
        static public List<KeyValuePair<Tkey,Tvalue>>
            AddExtensionDictionary<Tkey, Tvalue>(this List<KeyValuePair<Tkey, Tvalue>> dictionary, KeyValuePair<Tkey, Tvalue>  added)
        {
            dictionary.Add(added);
            return dictionary;
        }
    }
```